# Fully update a temporary table SQL

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, temporary

I have a problem: I am trying to fully update a temporary table (in a stored procedure) in SQL Server 2012, but it only updates the first entry that matches my description. Here is the code:

```
create table #t (store_name varchar(30),
                 product_name varchar(30), 
                 price int, 
                 valab_since date, 
                 valab_until date, 
                 best_offer varchar(3))

--some code that populates my table

update #t set best_offer = 'yes'
where price = (select min(price) from Cataloage as c 
                INNER JOIN Produse as p
                on c.codP = p.codP
                where p.denumire = #t.store_name)
update #t set best_offer = 'no'
where price > (select min(price) from Cataloage as c 
                INNER JOIN Produse as p
                on c.codP = p.codP
                where p.denumire = #t.product_name)

select * from #t
```

`Cataloage` and `Produse` are some tables that I use.

Answer (score 0):

To cover all records, first set them all to "no", then run a separate query just to update the ones with the MIN price for the store.

```
update #t set best_offer = 'no';

;with t as (
    select *, rnk = dense_rank() over (partition by t.store_name order by price asc)
    from Cataloage c
    join Produse p on c.codP = p.codP
    join #t t on p.denumire = t.store_name
)
update t
set best_offer = 'yes'
where rnk = 1;
```

I've used DENSE_RANK and a common table expression as an alternative to your row-by-row subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I had to make some little modifications, but essentially it did the trick.